# Why can I assign True = False (Python 2.7.9)

Tags: python

Why am I able to assign the Python keyword `True` to equal the Python keyword `False` using Python 2.7.9?

```
Python 2.7.9 (v2.7.9:648dcafa7e5f, Dec 10 2014, 10:10:46)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
>>> True
True
>>> True = False
>>> True
False
>>>
```

But when switching over to Python 3.4.3:

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
>>> True = False
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to keyword
>>>
```

Comment: Did you try Googling something like "python true false assign to keyword"?

Comment: This is the same thing as assigning `max` to `100` or `input` to `'Hello'`.

Comment: Am I the only one who read this question and immediately thought "I guess they changed it to a keyword, cool"? All the answers basically just repeat the question and add "yes, this occurs."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

True and False were builtins in Python 2, but in Python 3 they are keywords — thus the error message.  Strictly speaking, you're not assigning to them but shadowing them — which you can't do with a keyword.

Answer (score 2):

In python 3.x, `True` and `False` are [reserved words](https://docs.python.org/3.0/reference/lexical_analysis.html#id8)

Comment: They know that, they pointed that out in their 2nd example. Re-read the question.

Comment: @CoryKramer, Sorry if my answer wasn't clear.  You can do this in python 2.x because True and False are not [reserved words](https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/keywords.html).

Answer (score 2):

Because in Python 3.X it's a keyword, and in 2.7.X it's a variable (as `True=4869` works too, as well as `False=[4,8,6,9]`)